# bitmap rotation causes an error

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I am converting each frame retrieved from the camera into a bitmap and i display it on an ImageView, but i found that the imageView contains a rotated bitmap so i wanted to rotate the bitmap 90 degrees to set it right. to achieve this,
i wrote the below code to rotate the bitmap 90 degrees, but at run time i receive

```
bitmap size exceeds 32bits
```

i referred to some posts to solve this issue, and one of them suggested to recycle each bitmap used, but it did not solve the problem.
please let me know why i am getting this error and how to solve it?

**code**:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        Bitmap b = values[0];

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(b.getWidth()-10, b.getHeight()-10);
        matrix.postRotate(90);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        mIVEdges.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

        b.recycle();
    }
```

Comment: Are You really need rotate image in `onProgressUpdate()` not in `doInBackground()`? If - yes - may be `publishProgress()` calls to often and many new `resizedBitmap` created.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 100x100 pixel bitmap, then

```
matrix.postScale(b.getWidth()-10, b.getHeight()-10);
```

will cause new bitmap to be scaled with 90 scale factor.

```
matrix.postScale(90, 90);
```

So output of new Bitmap is 9000x9000 pixel.

If you want to reduce size of new bitmap, you want to use scale factor > 0.0 and < 1.0

```
matrix.postScale(0.9f, 0.9f);
```

Comment: ok´, what if i want to maintain the same size of the bitmap, should it be matrix.postScale(1f, 1f)

Comment: Yes. To maintain same bitmap size you need to use scale factor of 1.0